# Tkinter button only works once when using a list

Tags: python, function, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I am trying to use a button to cycle through a list. It works once, but then doesn't respond to any other presses.

```
cards = ["2 of Diamonds", "3 of Diamonds"] #etc (don't want it to be too long)
```

```py
current = 0
def next():
   current=+1
   print("\"current\" variable value: ", current)
   card.config(text=cards[current])
next = Button(text="⇛", command=next, fg="White", bg="Red", activebackground="#8b0000", activeforeground="White", relief=GROOVE).grid(column=2, row=1)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Read up on [Tutorial - 9.2. Python Scopes and Namespaces](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`current` is a local variable that you initialize to `1` each time the function is called.

You need to do two things:

- declare `current` as global
- increment it correctly (`+=` rather than `=+`)

Example:

```
def next():
    global current
    current += 1
    ...
```